# Join in on an activity

Tags: grammar

I was listening to my teacher and got confused when she said "I tried to join in on an activity about kids" .

What does ON function in that sentence ?

Answer (score 1):

**in on**  [OED](http://www.oed.com/view/Entry/92969?rskey=6MXdMg&result=2&isAdvanced=false#eid731635)

> adv: participating in; being (one of a group) in possession of
>   knowledge concerning (something).

As in:

> "I tried to participate in [join **in on**] an activity about kids" .

and

> ‘M. Innes’ Appleby's Answer    Don't imagine I have the slightest
>   wish to be **in on** your muckraking.

Comment: I thought it was JOIN IN (phrasal verb) + on an activity